# Is there any camera in which I can adjust the gamma curve manually?

Tags: dslr, camera, gamma

I am eagerly looking for a camera in which I can adjust the gamma correction. The cameras that I have, do this correction by default (which are not adjustable) and I need to remove this correction. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Any camera which is capable of shooting RAW and a decent image processing tool can apply any tone curve you like. What are your cameras and what's your workflow for getting from the camera to a final image?

Comment: Without *some* amount of gamma correction, 8 bits is not enough for decent representation of an image. Since JPEG is only 8 bits it wouldn't make sense to offer that option.

Answer (score 5):

Get a camera that can save its raw data.  With the raw data, you can apply whatever brightness curve you want in post-processing.

There are many cameras out there that can save raw data.  Look around.  Pretty much most cameras above the point-and-shoot level can do this.  All pro and prosumer cameras can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to adjust the transfer curve of JPEGs — sRGB is a standard for a reason. 8bit JPEGs are intended for low-data density storage, and using a transfer curve is an important part of that encoding.

#### 8bit JPEGs are wholly inappropriate for linearized image data.

If you want linear, "no gamma" (which actually means gamma 1.0), then you want to use the *RAW* images from your camera, not the 8bit JPEG. All competent cameras offer a RAW option. RAW is linear (no gamma curve, or more precisely gamma 1.0) straight from the sensor, and before debayering.

From this RAW you can debayer into a linear-gamma1.0 image and save to a floating-point format such as **16bit half-float .EXR** which is the current preferred standard for storing linear image data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to undo or change the OECF in the camera, you could always do it in post. 
Just let the camera do a decent OECF (for perceptually uniform coding), then in post apply the inverse EOCF back to linear-light (like Raw), followed by your preferred OECF. 
Or combine the EOCF and OECF into a single EECF, and call it "tone mapping".

It is more important to consider how a 1D conversion curve is applied to 3D color data. Is it applied 3 times to R and G and B individually, or is it applied once to the Luma value and then the same gain applied to the 2 Chroma values ? And is that Luma+Chroma constant-Luminance or not ? All results will be different, at least for saturated colors. Tone mapping in color is not trivial.